How can a Callable return a value from a predefined void callback?
I am using a data-related API interface which has a key void callback function that is automatically invoked to mark the end of some IO operations. I want to make the class Callable<String> and use Future<String> result.
I struggle to figure how to make the Callable return a String. Making a String returnResult(){return this.result} function to call inside doesn't do.
Please advise.
It looks something like:
public class MyCallable implements someAPIWrapper, Callable<String> {
    
    String result;

    @Override
    public void endOfJobCallback() { //predefined API callback marking end of work
      /*
      usually read the data and write to a file, but not my case.
      how to return this.result string from here?
      */
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
      //some logic stuff
      //make API call to request a bunch of data
      //inside a loop to listen to incoming messages, receiving and appending to the *result* variable
      //end of all messages signalled by the ending callback, stop loop and return result var
    }

}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      MyCallable callable = new MyCallable();
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
      Future<String> future = executor.submit(callable);
      String result = future.get(); //blocking until result ready
    }
}


Who is calling endOfJobCallback()? In your comment you say that result is produced inside call(), why would you need to "return it inside endOfJobCallback()"?

What do you need the callable for? If you want it to return a string, just return that String from the call function. But who calls the Callable?

@MatteoNNZ, the API defined it and calling it automatically. I will receive data and populate into result in a loop, but I cannot know when is the end reached until that callback is invoked by the API to signal end of job so I can break from the loop and return data

@cyberbrain, I call the Callable from main to initiate multiple callable tasks and wait for their returns. I need the API to tell me it is done before I know the data streams have been received, and it tells me by entering into that void callback.

You can use an (atomic) Boolean to know when to stop looping:
public class MyCallable implements someAPIWrapper, Callable<String> {
    
    String result;
    private volatile boolean complete = false;

    @Override
    public void endOfJobCallback() { //predefined API callback marking end of work
      complete = true; //set Boolean to true atomically so that the other method will know you have been called
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
      while (!complete) {
        //Do your stuff
      }
      //if you reach this the callback was called
      return result;
    }

}

Note: it is unclear how exactly you listen to messages because you didn't add any code. You may want to take the idea and adapt it to the real code depending on whether you short poll, you have a webhook etc

I figured using a flag as well. Setting it to true inside that callback to break from the !isDone loop. Thanks!

I guess a volatile boolean would work as well.

@DidierL you are right. Limestreetlab, in case you don't know, Didier's right because the variable is written by a single thread (the callback) so there's no need to be atomic. But if performance is not at stake both are fine

@MatteoNNZ, thanks. I just adopted your suggestion and is working now. Thanks for the advice.

@DidierL, thanks for the suggestion on CompletableFuture.

A volatile boolean is atomic. The difference to AtomicBoolean is that the latter provides additional atomic update operations which are not used in this code.

@Holger yep, volatile boolean is sufficient indeed, I've updated the code accordingly

You could make it work by adding a CompletableFuture in MyCallable, and complete it in endOfJobCallback().
public class MyCallable implements someAPIWrapper, Callable<String> {
    
    String result;
    CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

    @Override
    public void endOfJobCallback() { //predefined API callback marking end of work
      future.complete(result);
    }
}

and then in your main():
MyCallable callable = new MyCallable();
// do stuff with the API…

String result = callable.future.join(); //blocking until result ready

(of course this requires to make sure that endOfJobCallback() is called in 100% of the cases, otherwise you might need to implement some error handling, or you may want to use get(timeout, unit) instead of join())

I had thought something similar (using a CountDownLatch actually but same principle). But I think the problem is that you can't block the call() because it has to do stuff until when the callback is called.

Thanks. Did not know about the CompletableFuture.complete(result) call.

@limestreetlab it’s in the name of the class

@MatteoNNZ yeah that part of the question is not very clear

@DidierL, didn't read much about CompletableFuture, seems that newer class is closer to Javascript's Promise and CompletableFuture.complete is like Promise.resolve

@limestreetlab yeah… but note that when you say “newer”, it is actually 10 years old  Virtual Threads are probably going to replace most of its use cases now.

I think we will still see completable futures together with virtual threads. But with a lot more straight-forward join() calls rather than long chains of then… operations.

@Holger well, yes… but then the main benefit of CompletableFuture over plain Future is that join() doesn’t throw… OTOH ExecutorService.submit() returns Future and might make more sense to use if you don’t need the complete() and chaining features. I’m curious to see what’s coming with all of that :)

You may have to deal with APIs returning CompletableFuture anyway, for example java.lang.Process[Handle] or HttpClient. Sometimes, you may add a single .thenAcceptAsync(…, Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) or similar, to ensure that the subsequent operation runs in a virtual thread, regardless of how the source operation has been implemented, then, the subsequent operation may use calls like join() etc.
